# Spring JPA/ Hibernate - how update when object is not modified

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I can't update the entity because there are no changes but I need update its column *updated* o be used as tracking column. Below update entity column which I wish updating automatically even there is no changes.

**Entity**

```
@Column( name = "UPDATED" , nullable = true )
@DateTimeFormat( iso = ISO.DATE_TIME )
private LocalDateTime updated;

@PreUpdate
public void updatedEntry(){
    this.updated = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

**Spring JPA repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, BigDecimal>
{}
```

And below code is where I update values although sometimes the object won't modified because retrieved values are the same.

```
product.setBarcode( clfProduct.getBarcode() );
product.setTaxcode( clfProduct.getTaxcode() );
product.setPrice( clfProduct.getPrice() );
product.setMinOrder( clfProduct.getMinOrder() );
product.setMsrpPrice( clfProduct.getMsrpPrice() );
product.setStock( stock );

productRepository.save(product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the updated column a normal column you update, instead of using the `@PreUpdate` annotation.

Comment: I tried to avoid this way but I guess there is no way then. Thanks